# 2d numpy array, making each value the sum of the 3x3 square it is centered at

Tags: python, numpy

I have a square 2D numpy array, `A`, and an array of zeros, `B`, with the same shape.

For every index `(i, j)` in `A`, other than the first and last rows and columns, I want to assign to `B[i, j]` the value of `np.sum(A[i - 1:i + 2, j - 1:j + 2]`.

Example:

```
A =
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

B =
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 2, 0],
       [0, 4, 6, 3, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?  Or should I simply use a for loop?

Comment: How do you handle the edges? Is B[0][0] just A[0][0]+A[0][1]+A[1][0]?

Comment: I think for the edges I want to ignore them entirely.  So every edge element of B is equivalent to the edge element of A(zero)

Comment: Also I made a small edit to the indices, there was an error there.

Comment: Can't you use [`2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) and black out the border elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a clever (read "borderline smartass") way to do this with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). `as_strided` allows you to create views into your buffer that simulate windows by adding another dimension to the view. For example, if you had a 1D array like

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(3, x.shape[0] - 2), strides=x.strides * 2)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Hopefully it is clear that you can just sum along `axis=0` to get the sum of each size 3 window. There is no reason you couldn't extrend that to two or more dimensions. I've written the shape and index of the previous example in a way that suggests a solution:

```
A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A,
    shape=(3, 3, A.shape[0] - 2, A.shape[1] - 2),
    strides=A.strides * 2
)
B[1:-1, 1:-1] = view.sum(axis=(0, 1))
```

Summing along multiple axes simultaneously has been supported in [np.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) since v1.7.0. For older versions of numpy, just sum repeatedly (twice) along `axis=0`.

Filling in the edges of `B` is left as an exercise for the reader (since it's not really part of the question).

As an aside, the solution here is a one-liner if you want it to be. Personally, I think anything with `as_strided` is already illegible enough, and doesn't need any further obfuscation. I'm not sure if a `for` loop is going to be bad enough performance-wise to justify this method in fact.

For future reference, here is a generic window-making function that can be used to solve this sort of problem:

```
def window_view(a, window=3):
    """
    Create a (read-only) view into `a` that defines window dimensions.

    The first ``a.ndim`` dimensions of the returned view will be sized according to `window`.
    The remaining ``a.ndim`` dimensions will be the original dimensions of `a`, truncated by `window - 1`.

    The result can be post-precessed by reducing the leading dimensions. For example, a multi-dimensional moving average could look something like ::


         window_view(a, window).sum(axis=tuple(range(a.ndim))) / window**a.ndim

    If the window size were different for each dimension (`window` were a sequence rather than a scalar), the normalization would be ``np.prod(window)`` instead of ``window**a.ndim``.

    Parameters
    -----------
    a : array-like
        The array to window into. Due to numpy dimension constraints, can not have > 16 dims.
    window :
        Either a scalar indicating the window size for all dimensions, or a sequence of length `a.ndim` providing one size for each dimension.

    Return
    ------
    view : numpy.ndarray
         A read-only view into `a` whose leading dimensions represent the requested windows into `a`.
         ``view.ndim == 2 * a.ndim``.
    """
    a = np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True)
    window = np.array(window, copy=False, subok=False, dtype=np.int)
    if window.size == 1:
        window = np.full(a.ndim, window)
    elif window.size == a.ndim:
        window = window.ravel()
    else:
        raise ValueError('Number of window sizes must match number of array dimensions')

    shape = np.concatenate((window, a.shape))
    shape[a.ndim:] -= window - 1
    strides = a.strides * 2

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shake=shape, strides=strides)
```

Comment: I love your answer and upvoted it but it hurts my brain to think about it.. Post fits your name well xD

Answer (score 2):

I have found no 'simple' ways of doing this. But here are two ways:

---

- Still involves a for loop

```py
# Basically, get the sum for each location and then pad the result with 0's
B = [[np.sum(A[j-1:j+2,i-1:i+2]) for i in range(1,len(A)-1)] for j in range(1,len(A[0])-1)]
B = np.pad(B, ((1,1)), "constant", constant_values=(0))
```

---

- Is longer but no for loops (this will be a lot more efficient on big arrays):

```py
# Roll basically slides the array in the desired direction
A_right = np.roll(A, -1, 1)
A_left = np.roll(A, 1, 1)
A_top = np.roll(A, 1, 0)
A_bottom = np.roll(A, -1, 0)
A_bot_right = np.roll(A_bottom, -1, 1)
A_bot_left = np.roll(A_bottom, 1, 1)
A_top_right = np.roll(A_top, -1, 1)
A_top_left = np.roll(A_top, 1, 1)

# After doing that, you can just add all those arrays and these operations
# are handled better directly by numpy compared to when you use for loops
B = A_right + A_left + A_top + A_bottom + A_top_left + A_top_right + A_bot_left + A_bot_right + A

# You can then return the edges to 0 or whatever you like
B[0:len(B),0] = 0
B[0:len(B),len(B[0])-1] = 0
B[0,0:len(B)] = 0
B[len(B[0])-1,0:len(B)] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just sum the 9 arrays that make up a block, each one being shifted by 1 w.r.t. the previous in either dimension. Using slice notation this can be done for the whole array `A` at once:

```
B = np.zeros_like(A)
B[1:-1, 1:-1] = sum(A[i:A.shape[0]-2+i, j:A.shape[1]-2+j]
                    for i in range(0, 3) for j in range(0, 3))
```

#### General version for arbitrary rectangular windows

```
def sliding_window_sum(a, size):
    """Compute the sum of elements of a rectangular sliding window over the input array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        Two-dimensional input array.
    size : int or tuple of int
        The size of the window in row and column dimension; if int then a quadratic window is used.

    Returns
    -------
    array
        Shape is ``(a.shape[0] - size[0] + 1, a.shape[1] - size[1] + 1)``.
    """
    if isinstance(size, int):
        size = (size, size)
    m = a.shape[0] - size[0] + 1
    n = a.shape[1] - size[1] + 1
    return sum(A[i:m+i, j:n+j] for i in range(0, size[0]) for j in range(0, size[1]))
```